# Roslyn - SyntaxGenerator, generate AutoProperty

Tags: c#, roslyn

Is it somehow possible to generate an auto-property with the Roslyn `SyntaxGenerator` class (NOT `SyntaxFactory`)?

This:

```
var myProperty = generator.PropertyDeclaration("MyProperty", generator.TypeExpression(SpecialType.System_String), Accessibility.Public);
```

will generate:

```
public string MyProperty {
            get {
            }

            set {
            }
        }
```

I would like to have:

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Is this possible with some option? I found some solutions which uses `SyntaxFactory`, but i would like to use `SyntaxGenerator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible.

If you take a look at the [source](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/CodeGeneration/CSharpSyntaxGenerator.cs.html) for PropertyDeclaration you will notice, that unless the getter/setter is not declared or the property is abstract any getAccessorStatements/setAccessorStatements passed as null are set to an empty IEnumerable.

The generation of the accessors-statements then uses the AccessorDeclaration which will either return the accessors with a body (if the accessor is declared as null) or with a semicolon (if it is not null which is only possible for abstract properties as noted above).

There also seems to be an open [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3558) on github on this.